# How to dynamically bind img using props

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to bind dynamically the img using props but image is not displaying due to path.

I tried using require but unable to do so i.e `require('~@/assets/logo.png')`
Am I doing correct way?

```vue
<template>
  <swiper :options="swiperOption">
    <!-- slides -->
    <swiper-slide>
      <part picture="require('~@/assets/logo.png')" title="Pencard"/>
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <part picture="require('~@/assets/logo.png')" title="Register"/>
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <part picture="require('~@/assets/logo.png')" title="Service"/>
    </swiper-slide>

</template>

<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <img :src="picture"/>
        <div class="content">
          <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Image is not displaying.

Comment: Dont' require the same file thrice. Import it once, then use it where you need to.

Comment: I tried this as import Image from '@/assets/logo.png' and in return {  pic: Image, } in template <part picture="pic" title="Service"/> right? It is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this helps -

In your component:

```
const logo = require('~@/assets/logo.png');
```

In your html:

```
<part :picture="logo" title="Service"/>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. The only change required was I had to remove '~@' in require and make the logo as a property.

Answer (score 0):

You can import all images like that:

```
// correct your folder directory if I did it wrong 
const images = require.context('@/assets/', false, /\.jpg|\.png$/)
```

And then in methods add loadImg:

```
methods: {
  loadImg (path) {
    return images('./' + path)
  }
}
```

Then in template:

```
- <part picture="require('~@/assets/logo.png')" title="Pencard"/>
+ <part :picture="loadImg('logo.png')" title="Pencard"/>
```

Comment: <part picture="require('@/assets/logo.png')" title="Pencard"/> is loading properly. When I add other image above i.e <part picture="require('@/assets/register.png')" title="Image 2"/> this second image is not displaying.

Comment: The minus (-) shows you which line to delete, and the plus (+) with what you should replace it.

Comment: Sorry I meant I tried this only <part :picture="loadImg('register.png')" title="Image2"/> the image is not displaying.

Comment: So the first one does work and the second one doesn't?

Comment: Yes. first one is working and second one image is not displaying.

Comment: And do you have a 'register.png' file in your assets directory?